# PowerShell: Comparing folders via Hash

Tags: file, powershell, hash, directory, copying

I am trying to verify files inside folder after generating a hash for all the files.

I can successfully get the Hash output but I am having issues getting this working.

```
# Compare the files inside both folders togethor

$Results = @( Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $( Hash-Folder -Folder $FolderSource ) -DifferenceObject $( Hash-Folder -Folder $FolderDestination ) -Property Name, Hash -IncludeEqual:$False | Sort-Object -Unique | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String -Stream -Width 125 )

#If there are no differences, all is ok
If ( $Results -eq $NULL ) {

                Write-host "All files verified successfully"

            { Else {

                # There must be some differences, which side?

                ForEach ( $Result in $Results ) {

                    If ( $Result.SideIndicator -eq '<=' ) {

                    Write-Host "This file is different in the source " $Result.Trim()

                    }

                    If ( $Result.SideIndicator -eq '=>' ) {

                    Write-Host "This file is different in the destination " $Result.Trim()

                    }

                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Pretty unclear what you're asking here.

Comment: sorry, have tried to clear it up